# What weaponized vehicles can be used in Contact Missions?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I just played the new *GTA Online* Los Santos Drug Wars update "[First Dose](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/GTA_Online:_Los_Santos_Drug_Wars#First_Dose)" [Contact Missions](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Missions_in_GTA_Online) and was surprised to learn that my trusty Toreador, with its homing missiles, can't be used in those missions. The mechanic will not give the option to call in the Toreador (or the Scramjet, another weaponized vehicle) in the "First Dose" and "Last Dose" Contact Missions. The Toreador was always my vehicle of choice in Contact Missions, mainly because of its homing missiles.

**What weaponized vehicles can I use in *GTA Online* Contact Missions**, where the driver controls the weapons? Are there weaponized vehicles that are allowed in some Contact Missions but not in others? I want to make sure I have the right vehicle prepared as my active personal vehicle before I start a Contact Mission.

Answer (score 0):

The only vehicles I know (I'm not 100% sure though) that are weaponized and can be used in these missions are, I believe, the Vigilante and the Oppressor Mk II. Don't quote me on this, however, as I could be completely wrong. The last thing I want is for you to go and buy these vehicles and then have no use for them. Vigilante is 100% you can use.